# Finding the terminal point for $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

The problem:

[image: The problem]

Background: we haven't been taught $\sin$  and $\cos$ functions yet so I refrain from using those. Just by knowing the terminal point determined by $t = \frac{\pi}{3}$ is $\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2},\,\frac{1}{2}\right)$and symmetry, how do we solve the question?

I've tried to subtract the $y$-coordinate of the terminal point of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ from that of $(0, 1)$ to get the y-coordinate of the desired point, but it didn't work. I also tried to add up the coordinates of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ with itself and divide it by $2$, which didn't work.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider flipping the entire picture around the line $y = x$ that's drawn in orange. The curved arrow from $(1, 0)$ to $Q$ becomes an arrow from $(0, 1)$ to $P$. And in fact, under this transformation, $(1, 0)$ is sent to $(0, 1)$ and $Q$ is sent to $P$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

Let $A=(1,0)$, you can notice that $P$ is the mirror symetric of $A$ relatively to the line $(OQ)$.

---

The equation of $(OQ)$ is $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x$. Since $(PA)$ is orthogonal to $(OQ)$, its equation is $y=-\sqrt{3}x+a, a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let's determine $a$, $A=(1,0)$ is on $(PA)$, so it must verify the equation : $0=-\sqrt{3}+a$, so $a=\sqrt{3}$, so $y=-\sqrt{3}x+\sqrt{3}$.

Let $B$ be the intersection of $(OQ)$ and $(PA)$. We also have $AB=BP$. So let's calculate the coordinates of $B$. Let $B=(u,v)$, we have $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}u$ and $v=-\sqrt{3}u+\sqrt{3}$, so $v=-3v+\sqrt{3}$, so $v=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ and $u=\frac{3}{4}$. So $B=(\frac{3}{4},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4})$.

Finally we know that $AB=PB$. So let $P=(x_P,y_P),A=(x_A,y_A),B=(x_B,y_B)$, we have $x_B-x_A=x_P-x_B$ and $y_B-y_A=y_P-y_B$, so $x_P=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y_P=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: Didn't get it. How is P a line? How is it symmetric of point A?

Comment: I said a "line symetric", I wanted to say that $P$ is the mirror symetric of $A$ relatively to the line $(OQ)$.

Comment: Okay, I see that. But how does it help me solve the problem?

Comment: $(PA)$ is orthogonal to $(OQ)$, so you can find its equation. Then use this equation to find the coordinates of $P$.

Answer (score 0):

Let (*A*) be the point $(0,1)$.
Let (*B*) be the point $(1,0)$.
We are given (*Q*) to be $(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.
Let (*P*) be $(x,y)$.

The length of arc (*AP*) is equal to that of (*QB*). It follows that the length of line (*AP*) is also equal to that of (*QB*).

Using the distance formula:
$\sqrt{(y-1)^2 + (x-0)^2}$ =
$\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2} - 0)^2 + (\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} - 1)^2}$

=>$y^2-2y+1+x^2 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} - \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{2}+1$
=>$y^2+x^2-2y+1 = 2 - \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{2}$, since point (*P*) crosses the unit circle: $y^2+x^2 = 1$.
=>$2-2y = 2 - \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{2}$
=>$y = (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$.

Substitute the above value of $y$  into the unit circle equation to find x:

=>$(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2+x^2 = 1$.

=>$x^2 = 1 - (\frac{{3}}{4}) = (\frac{{1}}{4})$.

=>$x = \pm(\frac{{1}}{2})$. 
=> $x = (\frac{{1}}{2})$ , since we are in the first quadrant.